# django, How to set up function to modify models variables

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, function

i am new in django, please can somone explain me how this should work properly:

I have created app called taskai:

from django.db import models

```
# Create your models here.
class taskai(models.Model):
    title = models.TextField()
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='images/',null=True)
    desc = models.TextField(blank=True)
    inp = models.IntegerField(null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title

    def skaiciai(self, inp):
        for i in range(10):
            self.inp += i
        return print(self.inp)
```

i am just playing with models and functions in django, i want to print in site modified inp value. I am adding in admin panel title, image, desc and inp (for exmaple 5). Output should be 50, how can i make it work ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i am already solved by creating new function:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    for i in range(10)
         self.inp  += i
    super(taskai, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to do this to get the inp:

```
def skaiciai(self):
    for i in range(10):
        self.inp += i
    return print(self.inp)


aaa = taskai()

aaa.skaiciai()
```

you need to take out the "inp" on the method skaiciai. By receiving the self argument you will be able to call any class variable in a method.